# How can I `@CacheEvict` or `@CachePut` after transaction commit?

Tags: spring, caching

Why Spring `@CacheEvict` and `@CachePut` not invoke after transaction commit;
I think in this way,we can avoid some bug. For example,between evict cache and transaction commit,a `@Cacheable` invoke，then the value in cache is dirty data.
I saw `CacheInterceptor`,but it seen like I can't rewrite it.and someone can tell me,how can I `@CacheEvict` or `@CachePut` after transaction commit?

Answer (score 0):

if the `CacheManage` extends for `AbstractTransactionSupportingCacheManager`,you can invoke `setTransactionAware(true)`,then you @Cache invoke after transaction commit;